# MongoDB connection problems with Docker

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, debian

I am trying to use mongoDB on docker using Debian 10, but when I try to connect to it it gives me the following error.

In docker I followed the following steps:

1. `sudo docker pull mongo`
2. `sudo docker run -p 27017:27017 --name mymongo mongo`

and when I do a `mongo 127.0.0.1:27017` it returns

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
2021-01-27T22: 21: 26.647 + 0100 E QUERY [thread1] Error: network error while attempting to run command 'whatsmyuri' on host '127.0.0.1:27017':
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js: 231: 14
@ (connect): 1: 6

exception: connect failed
```

I have tried to do the `sudo mongo 127.0.0.1:27017` with the same result.

With the command `sudo docker exec -ti mymongo bash` I enter the container without any problem.

Regards.

**Update:**

I have tried on Windows and the steps I have followed work perfectly, so I do not know right now if it is a problem with Debian or the program used to connect

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the problem was with the `mongo` software that I have installed by repository, I have uninstalled it and installed the `.deb` from https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/shell and with the `mongosh` command it has connected correctly.